# Configuring Apache HttpClient to access service through proxy/load-balancer (overriding Host header)

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am having a problem getting the Apache HttpClient to connect to a service external to my virtualised development environment. 
To access the internet (e.g. api.twitter.com) I need to call a local URL (e.g. api.twitter.com.dev.mycompany.net), which then forwards the request to real host.

The problem is, that to whatever request I send, I get a 404 Not Found response.

I have tried debugging it using wget, and it appears the problem is, that the destination server identifies the desired resource by using both the request URL and the hostname in the Host header. Since the hostname does not match, it is unable to locate the resource.

I have (unsuccessfully) tried to override the Host header by setting the http.virtual-host parameter on the client like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
if (envType.isWithProxy()) {
    client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST, "api.twitter.com");
}
```

Technical details:

1. Client is used as an executor in RESTeasy to call the REST API. So "manually" setting the virtual host (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045911/how-can-i-override-the-host-header-in-the-request-when-using-apache-commons-ht)) is not an option.
2. Everything is done via HTTPS/SSL - not that I think it makes a difference.

**Edit 1:** Using a HttpHost instead of a String does not have the desired effect either:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
if (envType.isWithProxy()) {
    HttpHost realHost = new HttpHost("api.twitter.com", port, scheme);
    client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST, realHost);
}
```

**Edit 2:** Further investigation has revealed, that the parameter needs to be set on the request object. The following is the code v. 4.2-aplha1 of HttpClient setting the virtual host:

```
HttpRequest orig = request;
RequestWrapper origWrapper = wrapRequest(orig);
origWrapper.setParams(params);
HttpRoute origRoute = determineRoute(target, origWrapper, context);

virtualHost = (HttpHost) orig.getParams().getParameter(
            ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST);
```

`params`are the parameters passed from the client. But the value for 'virtualHost' is read from the request parameters.

So this changes the nature of the question to: How do I set the VIRTUAL_HOST property on the requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClientPNames.VIRTUAL_HOST` is the right parameter for overriding physical host name in HTTP requests. I would just recommend setting this parameter on the request object instead of the client object. If that does not produce the desired effect please post the complete wire / context log of the session (see [logging guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) for instructions) either here or to the HttpClient user list.

---

**Follow-up**

OK. Let's take a larger sledge hammer. One can override content of the `Host` header using an interceptor.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.addRequestInterceptor(new HttpRequestInterceptor() {

    public void process(
            final HttpRequest request, 
            final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        request.setHeader(HTTP.TARGET_HOST, "www.whatever.com");
    }
});
```

One can make the interceptor clever enough to override the header selectively, only for specific hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @oleg, and I think, you are right. :) Unfortunately, the request object is made by RESTeasy. I'll update the question.

Comment: @tveon: actually HttpClient level parameters should always propagate to individual requests. It just seems conceptually wrong to set 'Host' value for all requests indiscriminately.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Although we in REST generally operate with base URI to which all the actions relates to, I suppose there could be interactions (e.g. redirects), where the approach is not safe, and using an interceptor with some appropriate logic is probably better.