# Setting the virtual host port in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I use Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1 as a kind of reverse-proxy. This proxy server runs in a servlet container in port 8081, and proxies some of the requests to port 8080 on the same server. As the legacy server on port 8080 builds some absolute urls using the HTTP `Host` header, I want to explicitly set that header.

[It is not possible to set the Host-header as you set other headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6045911/227192), as HttpClient automatically overrides the value you set. The only way I've found to change the `Host`-header is to set the virtual host:

```
HttpClient = ...
HttpMethod = ...

HostParams hostParams = new HostParams();
hostParams.setVirtualHost("localhost:8081"); 
hostConfiguration.setParams(hostParams);
hostConfiguration.setHost("localhost", 8080);

client.executeMethod(hostConfiguration, method);
```

But this doesn't work as it should because HttpClient seems to add the port it connects to, to the `Host`:

```
11:07:05.011 [qtp1813719644-21] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header - >> "Host: localhost:8081:8080[\r][\n]"
```

Is it any way I can fix this behaviour? If not, does Apache Httpclient 4.x behave differently?

Comment: I don't think you need to set the port, the Host can be changed as many hosts names can have the same IP but there's is only on port: the one to which you are opening the connection. `hostParams.setVirtualHost("localhost");`

Comment: @gma That will make the legacy application send "Location: http://localhost:8080∕foo", and create some links at other places with  port 8080 in the url. [The port is a part of the Host-header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23).

Comment: Yes, but it is not relevant except for proxies which HttpClient is not.

Comment: @gma well, it is relevant for me now :) HttpClient provides exactly what I need, except for this issue

Comment: did you try to set the proxy of httpclient to `localhost:8081` and setting the url normally to `localhost:8080`. I don't really know if it can work as HttpClient is not a proxy but may be seen as like a transparent proxy.

Comment: @gma Using a proxy worked (with 8080 as the proxy). That makes all the requests have absolute URLs, but I don't find any practical problems with that. If you add an answer with: hostConfiguration.setProxy("localhost", 8080);
hostConfiguration.setHost("localhost", 8081); I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your problem is traversing a proxy (which in your case is a Servlet+HTTPClient), configure your client to use `localhost:8080` as proxy and url as *normal*: `http://localhost:8081/...` :

```
hostConfiguration.setProxy("localhost", 8080);
hostConfiguration.setHost("localhost", 8081);
```