# How to customise "host" header in Java http client

Tags: java, http2, java-10, java-11, java-http-client

Here's my code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8081/"))
    .header("Host", "test.example.com")
    .build();
client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

As a result I see that the above code sends:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
Content-Length: 0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8081
HTTP2-Settings: AAEAAEAAAAIAAAABAAMAAABkAAQBAAAAAAUAAEAA
Upgrade: h2c
User-Agent: Java-http-client/10
Host: test.example.com
```

As you can see it sends two `Host` headers (the one from URI and the one I specified), but I would like it to send the `Host` header that I specified, not the one from the URI.
Is it possible with this client?

EDIT: In Java 11, it gets even worse (you need to change the client.send line to: `client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());`):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: restricted header name: "Host"
```

How can I customize that header (needed for testing of virtual hosts)?

I also tried the `setHeader` and get exactly the same problem (either double `Host` headers, or the exception).

EDIT: I reported a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210740).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of Java 12 (EA build 22) it has been solved by additional property `jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders` (see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213696).

So now one can override `Host` (or any other restricted header) by executing the code with:

```
java -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host ...
```

Allowing multiple restricted headers are as follows:

```
java -Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=connection,content-length,host
```

and you can set it up in the eclipse menu > Run > Run Cunfigurations
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The behavior from the Java11 client code seems correct. The [Host](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) section elaborates on the details. By the way, from the documentation of `HttpRequest` builder `header(String name, String value)` :

```
*    @throws IllegalArgumentException if the header name or value is not
*    valid, see <a href="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2">
*    RFC 7230 section-3.2</a>, or the header name or value is restricted
*    by the implementation.
```

***Update***: See this, for answer [pertaining to JDK/12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53616986/1746118).

Comment: Yes, but e.g. Apache HttpClient allows customization of that header since some time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045911/how-can-i-override-the-host-header-in-the-request-when-using-apache-commons-ht similarly curl allows customization of Host header (it takes precedence over the URL). So it is a reasonable expectation have same functionality in this http client.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń Though I am not in the position to define the reason why the implementation of the other clients differs. Yet to what I could further dig into is that [RFC2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) specifies the same and the answer to [what is the http host header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156023/what-is-http-host-header) also emphasizes on the note that the URI should be such that the host and the port should be read from it.

Comment: While you are correct according to the RFC, but almost all web clients allow some level of customization - which is very convenient thing for developers, e.g. I would expect to be able to override all headers that are produced by given http client - this allows easy debugging of the applications being developed.

Comment: It is the correct answer for java 11, let's hope it will change in some next release.