# Why okHttp can add Host params in Headers?

Tags: okhttp, java-11, host

This is JDK11`s [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315472/how-to-customise-host-header-in-java-http-client#/).The header name or value is restricted by the implementation.But Why OKHttp can add Host in Header? Use JDK11.

Comment: Maybe okhttp has their own complete implementation of HTTP from the client side.

Comment: oh,i will see source code.